# Fetch query string value from URL with NuxtJS and AsyncData method

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, asyncdata

I try to fetch value of the name parameter in URL: http://fakelocalhost:3000/page?name=test

I'm using **NuxtJS** (v2.11.0) and **TypeScript**, with *nuxt-property-decorator* package (v2.5.0).

But, I get an undefined result with `console.log(params.name)`.

Here, my full TS code:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import {
    Component,
    Vue
  } from "nuxt-property-decorator";

  @Component({
    asyncData({ params  }) {
      console.log(params.name);
    }
  })
  export default class extends Vue {}
</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution...

```
asyncData({ route }) {
   console.log(route.query.name);
}
```

Use *route* object instead of *params* in **asyncData** method.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the context parameter: query
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/context#query

```
asyncData({ query }) {
   console.log(query.name);
}
```